# Separate columns in one line using Bash script

Tags: bash, awk

I am using bash scripting in Linux. I have a variable that looks like this:

```
a="1-1-1 1-1-2 1-1-3 1-1-4"
```

I want to separate columns with values equal to or greater than 1-1-3 using AWK.

My output should be:

```
1-1-3 1-1-4
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: How do you define "greater than"? What about `a="2-1-1 1-1-2 1-1-3 1-1-4"` ?

Comment: I think at first , column one should be compared then two and three, regarding to your example, output will be 2-1-1 1-1-3 1-1-4. if our data is single column I can use echo "$a | awk '($0 >= 1-1-3) {print $0}' ... but now I have input in one line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it without a loop, if you use the space as record separator:

```
echo $a | awk -v RS=' ' -v ORS=' ' '{$1=$1} $1>="1-1-3"'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop over the line and compare:

```
echo $a | awk -v ORS=' ' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i >= "1-1-3") print $i;}'
```

Answer (score 1):

sort's `-V` option gives you "version" sorting that might be helpful:

```
$ a="2-0-0 1-1-1 1-1-2 1-1-3 1-1-4"
$ tr ' ' '\n' <<<"$a" | sort -V
1-1-1
1-1-2
1-1-3
1-1-4
2-0-0
```